# Sockets (TCP/UDP) on iPad WITHOUT Objective-C

Tags: ipad, sockets, wifi, real-time, arduino

Is there a way to make use of iPad/iPhone's socket capabilities **without using Objective-C**? Is there any way to expose this functionality with [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) 3 or some über HTML5 framework?

On the Arduino forums I'm trying to find out my hardware limits, [here](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,102852.0.html) and [here](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,104487.0.html) (I found out that using Objective-C this would be possible, even with bonjour discovery).

[image: This is what I would like to achieve]

(With webSockets, or with UDP. It doesn't have to be Haxe.)

I'm researching the possibility of using webSockets, which should be the easiest if it's possible.
However, I'd like to consider all options. So I know Arduino can talk [raw UDP](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,99362.msg768205.html#msg768205). And I know that there is a CocoaAsyncSocket library for Objective-C. Only, I'd like to NOT prototype in Objective-C...

(So, this will be the n-th post on Stack Overflow about a Wi-Fi-enabled Arduino that I'd like to talk to an [iDevice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDevice). Bluetooth is not an option due to Apple's non-prototyping-friendly-MFi-program.)

Comment: Don't know about the protyping without objective-C. But does the iPhone support bluetooth keyboards? Sparkfun has a bluetooth module that comes pre-loaded with HID firmware that makes the device present itself as a keyboard, and it is capable of sending keystrokes to the host machine. Perhaps this is a way you could bypass the MFI thing you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the C POSIX socket API (probably easiest, if you know C). Or you can use HTML5/Javascript and Haxe or socket.io.

Comment: thanks. I've decided to go with HaXe (HTML5) for the prototype, i can build a proof of concept using webSockets. The 'real' version should be written in native Obj-C / C (using a socket API).